# AWSSDK V2 Java SES sending email - AmazonSimpleEmailService cannot be resolved

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am trying to integrate aws SES SDK v2 to send emails in the application and this is my initial project with aws sdk.
However, I am following below example from the docs but the main classes are not able to resolve even though I have added proper dependencies in gradle.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html

Gradle dependencies added:

    `implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.10.36')
    implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 'ses', version: '2.10.36'`

Is there any other dependencies I am missing? I see that intellij has all dependent jars in the project for the above. But still no luck in finding the jars for the below classes.

`AmazonSimpleEmailService
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, there are quite few changes in client classes between 1.x to 2.x versions.
Both of below classes are removed from sdk.

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
```

In place of them, SesClient and SesClientBuilder are provided which works fine.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/LaunchChangelog.md

Here is sample code:

```
SesClient client = SesClient.builder()
  .region(Region.of(emailRegion))
  .build();
SendEmailRequest request = SendEmailRequest.builder()
  .source(fromAddress)
  .destination(destination)
  .message(message)
  .build();
client.sendEmail(request);
```